# How to reset getTagProps in material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, material-ui

Iam using material UI, I have a scenario, If user selects a Country, another autocomplete inputbox have to show a appropiate states. It shows the states but the issue was if user change the state, the number of state selected before was not changed. I don't know how to reset the tagValue, since its from the material UI and internally set. Do we have option to reset it by prop?

Issue Scenario:

1. user Select a country, in state box shows appropriate state. If I clicked more states it gives the count with +3 ( which are selected).
   2.user Change the country, the state box cleared but the count reamins there. If I select state in the state box, It add with the existing count (+4,+5)

```
import { Autocomplete, Chip, TextField, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import { times } from 'lodash';
import InitialSpinner from 'common/InitialSpinner';

function AutocompleteSelect(props) {
  const {
    options,
    optionLabel,
    label,
    name,
    variant,
    maxLength,
    setFieldValue,
    value,
    multi,
    loading,
    error,
    helperText,
    onChange
  } = props;

  const updatedOptions = options.reduce((acc, data) => ({ ...acc, [data.id]: data[optionLabel] }), {});
  const getRenderTag = (tagValue, getTagProps) => {
    if (tagValue.length <= maxLength) {
      return tagValue.map((option, index) => {
        console.log(updatedOptions[option], tagValue, getTagProps);
        return (
          updatedOptions[option]
        && (
          <Chip
            label={updatedOptions[option]}
            size="small"
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
            {...maxLength === 2 && ({ sx: { maxWidth: 'calc(50% - 35px) !important' } })}
          />
        )
        );
      });
    }
    const array = times(maxLength, (index) => (
      updatedOptions[tagValue[index]]
      && (
        <Chip
          label={updatedOptions[tagValue[index]]}
          size="small"
          {...getTagProps({ index })}
          {...maxLength === 2 && ({ sx: { maxWidth: 'calc(50% - 35px) !important' } })}
        />
      )
    ));
    array.push(
      <Tooltip
        key={tagValue}
        title={tagValue.slice(maxLength, tagValue.length).map((tag) => updatedOptions[tag]).join(', ')}
        placement="right-start"
      >
        <Chip
          label={`${tagValue.length - maxLength}+`}
          size="small"
        />
      </Tooltip>
    );
    return array;
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple={multi}
      options={Object.keys(updatedOptions)}
      value={value}
      loading={loading}
      getLimitTagsText={(more) => `+${more}`}
      renderTags={getRenderTag}
      loadingText={<InitialSpinner />}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => updatedOptions[option] || ''}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, selectedValue) => option === selectedValue}
      onChange={(e, val) => {
        setFieldValue?.(name, multi && val === null ? [] : val);
        onChange?.(val);
      }}
      sx={multi ? {
        '& input': {
          minWidth: 'unset !important'
        }
      } : {}}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label={label}
          name={name}
          variant={variant}
          error={error}
          helperText={helperText}
          {...params}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

AutocompleteSelect.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  optionLabel: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.node]),
  name: PropTypes.string,
  variant: PropTypes.string,
  maxLength: PropTypes.number,
  onBlur: PropTypes.func,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  setFieldValue: PropTypes.func,
  value: PropTypes.any,
  multi: PropTypes.bool,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  helperText: PropTypes.any
};

AutocompleteSelect.defaultProps = {
  optionLabel: 'value',
  variant: 'outlined',
  maxLength: 2,
  multi: true
};

export default AutocompleteSelect;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean "if user change the state, the number of state selected before was not changed."? is it the scenario when you select a country and it's states are filled in the second dropdown and then you change the country and now you have the new country's states plus the previous country's state in the dropdown?

Comment: No, I will tell you step by step.
1. user Select a country, in state box shows appropriate state. If I clicked more states it gives the count with +3 ( which are selected).
2.user Change the country, the state box cleared but the count reamins there. If I select state in the state box, It add with the existing count (+4,+5)

Comment: okay what property is responsible for showing the number of selected states? is it a state variable? do you check for an `onChange` event on the first dropdown to reset it?
if you already manage your logic in a function that you already supply to the dropdown `onChange` you can just reset there. first thing before you do anything `setCounter(0)` or something like that